# IOS-Charts cannot show any x-axis labels in a line chart

Tags: ios-charts

(Hopefully simple question) 
How do I get X-axis labels to show. I want four words to show in a line chart with multiple plots.

The plots and everything else works beautifully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the x-axis labels title when you create the LineChartData object:

```
let chartData = LineChartData(xVals: labels, dataSet: dataSet)
chartView.data = chartData
```

The xVals parameter is the x-axis label title array.

You can check out how it's done in the example project: https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts, ChartsDemo folder